# Why hasn't DRAM speed kept up with CPU speed as technology improves?

Tags: cpu, dram, performance

In 1976, the Z80 processor ran at 2.5 MHz and a typical DRAM access time was 500 ns. Now, processors run at 4 GHz and DRAM access time is 50 ns. Thus, processors are over three orders of magnitude faster but DRAM accesses are only one order of magnitude faster.

What are the technical reasons for this?

Why doesn't scaling help DRAM the same way it helps CPUs?

My hypothesis is that manufacturers increase DRAM capacity as transistors shrink, so the bit lines remain about the same length. Thus, the bit line capacitance doesn't scale down much and R-C delays on the bit lines keep DRAMs slow. Would a 1970s-sized 1-kilobit DRAM keep up with CPU speeds with modern technology, or are there other limiting factors?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe L1 cache - which nowadays has an access time on the order of 1 ns - would make a fairer comparison. Caches are far more critical nowadays than they were in the 70s.

Comment: Maybe @TypeIA is on the right path.  DRAM is external to the chip, and thus has lots of capacitance to contend with vs internal on die memory.

Comment: DRAM is a relatively slow type of memory to begin with. It trades cost for speed.

Comment: There are lots of reasons and it would take me time to consider my own memory of such things. But earlier memory systems were quite different than today's. So  a survey of these differences would give a starting point. Also, when designing a CPU, one can anticipate each stage quite accurately, and most especially one can anticipate the loads and therefore exactly size the drivers for the loads. But as soon as you go *off-chip* those loads become unknown, the drivers large, bulky, and slow, the memory layout configurable, etc. And this is at least part of it.

Comment: @TypeIA While caches are an interesting topic, for this question I'm specifically interested in dynamic RAM.

Comment: Because cache. It's more important to improve the density of DRAM than to improve its speed. And density has improved about 5 orders of magnitude ... maybe nearer 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is the DRAM is located far away from the CPU, and the bus speed determines the bandwidth of data that the chip can handle.

The bus speed is determined by PCB design and layout and not chip design, things like trace/net timing and termination affect the clock speed of the memory and not the chip itself. Trace width and length, The PCB dielectric constant, PCB thickness, copper weight all determine how fast the clock speed of the memory. This has limits and is hard to achieve high speeds. The higher speed that is needed the more these constraints need to be controlled.

Maintaining clock speeds on the same chip is a bit easier because of the distance involve, it's much shorter and easier to maintain high speeds.

The other problem is the speed of accessing DRAM is done with amplifiers that must read a row/column and these can only operate so fast, so the refresh is limited by the size of the DRAM and the analog sense circuitry and the column and row addressing. That has improved but it does not scale like mores law does. You can see the [improvements over time here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency)

[image]
Source: https://slideplayer.com/slide/4139713/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. A 3 GHz DRAM bus would add under a nanosecond of delay, however, so I don't think the bus explains why an access takes 50 ns.

Comment: Forgot about that part.

Comment: @KenShirriff: What 3GHz bus do you know of with 64 or more parallel data signals?

Comment: The access is due to the structure of the Column Address System, but that isn't what determines the bandwidth of the DRAM or how fast it runs, that is determined by the PCB. CAS runs a few clocks slower than the main clock

Comment: @BenVoigt They tricked me by specifying DDR4 speeds as twice the actual bus speed :)

Comment: @KenShirriff: The DRAM clock speed (or oversampling I/O speed) determines burst throughput.... transfer time between successive words moving in the same direction.  That is indeed down near 1ns, and can be less than the round-trip delay through I/O buffers and synchronizers.  The *access time* you asked about in your question, is to setup access to an arbitrary address, sent from memory controller to DRAM, and then do an access.  That requires bidirectional data flow.